# Mapping an IAM role to a Cloud Identity organizational unit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-identity

In the GCP IAM console, I can add either the entire organization (the domain of example.com) or individual users to Roles. However, I have the users setup in GSuite/Cloud Identity and organized into OUs that I'd like to use.

Is there a way to map members of an Organizational Unit (OU) (in Cloud Identity) to an IAM Role (in GCP IAM)?

Answer (score 0):

The users in GSuite/ Cloud Identity cannot be transferred automatically to GCP, because IAM roles are subject to only in GCP.
You can create groups in GSuite and add them individually to [GCP IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/quickstart#grant_an_iam_role).